# adding a column name in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
library(quantmod)
quote<-c("0883.HK","0386.HK","0857.HK")
df1<-data.frame(getQuote(quote)$Last)
```

Just download the last traded price for some stocks and put those quotes in a data frame, and then what I am trying to do here is to add column names for those quotes like below:

```
colnames(df1)<-c("883","386","857")

Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

May I ask what have I done wrong here? Million thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The data you selected is one column with three observations. Therefore you cannot assign it three names as there is only one column

```
> df1
  getQuote.quote..Last
1                10.00
2                 3.74
3                 3.55
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out, now it works perfectly after I converted the df to list

Answer (score 1):

When we apply `as.data.frame` or `data.frame` on a `vector` (after extracting the `Last` column), it will be a single column with that vector as values of the column.  We may need to convert to `list` and then setting the column names will work

```
df1 <- as.data.frame.list(getQuote(quote)$Last)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, so good to see ur rapid responses everytime  :)